# JSON dependency/condition for value assignment between different entries

Tags: json

I have a json file as below where I want to set the value of `['JKL']['A']` i.e *"sample"* based on what is chosen in `['list']['schema']['properties']['MNO']` i.e *'value1', 'value2', 'value3'*.

I am thinking this is possible using the 'oneof' dependency in JSON schema but have no clue on how to proceed. Is this even possible?

And of course, I'd like to select one out of at least two values for `['JKL']['A']`, say if `['MNO']` is *'value1'*, `['JKL']['A']` should be assigned *"sample2"* and if `['MNO']` is *'value2'*, `['JKL']['A']` should be assigned *"sample1"*.

```
`{
  "ABC": "XXXXXX",
  "DEF": "XXXXX",
  "GHI": "XXXXXX",
  "JKL": {
    "A": "sample",
    "B": "XXXX",
    "C": "XXXXXX"
  },
  "list": {
    "schema": {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "MNO": {
          "D": "XXXXX",
          "E": "XXXXX",
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3"
          ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}`
```